# Is it a way to use a mix of Annotation and Simple module for deserialization?

Tags: java, json, annotations, deserialization

I need to deserialize a json file, with 3 différents properties.

Edit : Or, how could i deserialize `List<User> optional and mandatory` in AudienceDeserialization, ( unknown size )

Audiance Classe:

```
public class Audience {
    Entity entity;
    private Integer stageBor;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = MandatoryDeserialize.class)
    private List<User> mandatory;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = OptionalDeserialize.class)
    private List<User> optional;
// ....
```

Json file

```
[
  {
    "entity": "BFA",
    "stageBor": "1",
    "mandatory": [
        { "email": "11test@test.com"},
        { "email": "11test@test.com"}
    ],
    "optional": [
        { "email": "12test@test.com"},
        { "email": "12test@test.com"},
        { "email": "12test@test.com"},
        { "email": "12test@test.com"}
    ]
  },
    {
    "entity": "EX",
    "stageBor": "2",
    "mandatory": [
         { "email": "21test@test.com"},
        { "email": "21test@test.com"},
        { "email": "21test@test.com"}
    ],
    "optional": [
        { "email": "22test@test.com"},
        { "email": "22test@test.com"},
        { "email": "22test@test.com"}
    ]

  },
  {
    "entity": "IT",
    "stageBor": "3",
    "mandatory": [
         { "email": "31test@test.com"},
        { "email": "31test@test.com"},
        { "email": "31test@test.com"}
    ],
    "optional": [
         { "email": "33test@test.com"},
        { "email": "33test@test.com"},
        { "email": "33test@test.com"}
    ]
  }
]
```

MandatoryDeserialize

```
public class MandatoryDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<List<User>> {

    @Override
    public List<User> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, IOException {
        InnerItems innerItems = jp.readValueAs(InnerItems.class);

        return innerItems. mandatory;
    }

    private static class InnerItems {
        public List<User>  mandatory;
    }
}
```

OptionalDeserialize

```
public class OptionalDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<List<User>> {
    @Override
    public List<User> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, IOException {
        InnerItems innerItems = jp.readValueAs(InnerItems.class);

        return innerItems.optional;
    }

    private static class InnerItems {
        public List<User> optional;
    }
```

AudienceDeserialization

```
public class AudienceDeserialization extends StdDeserializer<Audience> {

    public AudienceDeserialization() {
        this(null);
    }
    private AudienceDeserialization(Class<?> vc)
    {
        super(vc);
    }

    public Audience deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        String nameEntity = node.get("entity").asText();
        entity = entity.searchEntity(ListEntities.entities,nameEntity);
        Integer stageBor =  node.get("stageBor").asInt();
       // String email = node.get("email").asText();

        return new Audience(entity,stageBor, null, null);
```

MAIN

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Audience.class, new AudienceDeserialization());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        TypeReference<List<Audience>> typeReferenceAudience = new TypeReference<>() {};
        FileInputStream inputStreamAudience = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\oraph\\Desktop\\audience.json");
        try {
            List<Audience> audiences = mapper.readValue(inputStreamAudience, typeReferenceAudience);

            System.out.println("Users Saved!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to save users: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

As we can see, i uses two classes of deserialization with annotation
and one classe with simple module.
But only simple Module work and my annotation doesnt work.

Is it a way to use both in same time ?

Comment: I don't see why you would need other deserializers for that task. Both "mandatory" and "optional" are plain objects in an array and Jackson is able to handle that. If you want to verify that "mandatory" contains users, then that's out of scope of Jackson and should be done with something else, like `javax.validation`.

Comment: Because mandatory and optional are unknow list size, and i just get the email. And how should i do with Jakson? thx u

Comment: Just remove both `@JsonDeserialize(...)` annotation, the deserialization should work out-of-the-box, when the `User` model is correct for your use case. If `User` is a bigger class with more properties than use `email`, then just create a different model for a small user object containing only the email address.

Comment: ok, And in AudienceDeserialization, how i bind mandatory and optionnal list? I need this class to retrieve entity (with searchEntity) thx

Comment: You shouldn't need that AudienceDeserialization either. What error/exception do you get when you don't register that deserialization module?

Comment: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('BFA'). He cant figure out what is entity